# rails_admin multiple image uploading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, field, rails-admin

I want to make something like gallery of photos for each of my product in `rails_admin`.

But for different products I want to add different amount of photos.

So, I've got my `Product` model with `has_one :gallery` association and my `Gallery` model with `belongs_to :product` association.

How can I have multiple fields in `rails_admin model`, when I don't know how many fields, will I need exactly?

Or how can I upload multiple files through Paperclip in rails_admin ?

Comment: Nice comment, you helped me very much. Thanks, man.

Comment: No problem. I'm a good encourager of autodidacticism.

Answer (score 3):

You could use accepts_nested_attributes_for

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :gallery, inverse_of: photos
   has_attached_file :image
end

class Gallery 
   has_many :photos
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
end
```

And this would get you something like this:

[image]

Notice how you could have as many photos as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This question lost its relevance after 4 years unfortunately :)

Comment: haha yeah noticed that moments after answering it.
I thought i could be useful to googlers in the future anyway.